# Specify anonymous ftp password in ftp command

Tags: login, password, ftp, sftp, .netrc

I would like a simple (ideally one-liner, without separate script file) command to connect to an ftp server via anonymous login using my email address as the password.

My attempt is based on the syntax [as shown here](https://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/user-pass-url.html) of basically `ftp username:password@hostname`; however this does not work for me when the password itself, being an email address, has an @ sign..

I also tried to provide a netrc file as a heredoc, as so: `ftp hostname -N <<< 'login anonymous password user@email.com'` but this still prompts me for a password during the ftp login..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lftp

**example:**

```
    lftp -u user,pass ftp.example.com
```